# the first $2k$ terms of the power series of $\sec x + \tan x$ at $x=-\pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, power-series

We know the power series of $\sec x+\tan x$ is as follows,

$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{E_n}{n!}x^n$, where $E_n$ is [Euler Zigzag numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation#Related_integer_sequences) and clearly the radius of convergence of $f(x)$ is $\pi/2$.

Suppose $f_k=\sum_{n\geq 0}^{2k-1}\frac{E_n}{n!}x^n$, i.e., the sum of the first $2k$ terms.

Obviously $f(x)$ diverges at $-\frac\pi2$. However it seems $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f_k(-\frac{\pi}2)$ converges.

I calculated first several terms of $f(x)$ and found $f_k(-\frac\pi 2)$ seems to converge to $-\frac2\pi$.

But I have no idea to prove it. Can someone give me some hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just computed it to 500 terms, and it seems to approach the value $-.6366197723675813430755350534900574481378385829618$

Comment: In fact, it looks like $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{E_n}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n=1.2732395447351626861510701069801148962756771659213$, which is half of the value above, which means the terms are just oscillating around zero

Comment: I think the real question to ask is what the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{E_n}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$ is. That would also solve your current problem.

Comment: Thanks, Pauly. The value of $2/\pi\approx$0.63661977236758 is almost what you got. That's why I want to show the limit exists and equals $-\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 4):

By [Abel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem), if the power series converges, then it agrees with the limit of the function.

This argues against $-2/\pi$. Instead, either the power series converges to $0$ (by the limit Michael & Ewan give in the other answer) or it does not converge.

---

Some messing around numerically: It looks like the *terms* of the sum (not the sum itself) approach $(-1)^n 4/\pi$.

---

Computation of the sum of first $2k$ terms, as $k \rightarrow \infty$:

As Winther said, we're adding up $$\left(\frac{E_{2n}}{(2n)!} - \pi/2 \frac{E_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\left(\pi/2\right)^{2n}$$

This is exactly the Maclaurin series for $g(x) = \mathrm{sec}(x) - \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{tan}(x)/x$ evaluated at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

We need: 1. Convergence of the series at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. And 2. The limit of the function to be as desired.

Here's 2:

$\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \mathrm{sec}(x) - \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{tan}(x)/x = \mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x - \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{sin}(x)}{x\, \mathrm{cos}(x)} = \mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{cos}(x)}{\mathrm{cos}(x) - x\, \mathrm{sin}(x)} = \frac{1}{-\pi/2} = -\frac{2}{\pi}$.

For 1, notice $g(z)$ is holomorphic out past $\pi/2$ (only possible poles are at $\pm \pi/2$ and the limit for $-\pi/2$ is $2/\pi$ and we already computed the limit at $+\pi/2$).

Comment: Hi aes, thanks for replying. Obviously the power series isn't convergent, which is written in the post. What I concern is the sum of the first $2n$ terms as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I've edited my post, computing the limit except for the detail of proving it converges.

Comment: I added a note on convergence as well.

Comment: Very nice. btw it is also possible to show convergence directly by using asymptotic formulas for $E_{2n},E_{2n+1},n!$, but this is much more messy so I prefer the argument here.

Comment: @Winther I was looking for how to make such an argument, by extracting more terms from the two approximations (approximating in terms of bernoulli numbers, then approximating those by Stirling's formula), but I didn't see a similar approximation for the even terms. I see that [Stanley's article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4240) has good enough approximations to do it, but he uses residues, which I suppose is pretty similar to what I've done here. Do you know good enough approximations of the even terms by other means?

Comment: The even terms are just normal Euler numbers $E_{2n} = (-1)^{n}E^{\rm euler}_{2n}$ which have well known asymptotics (see e.g. Eq. 20-21 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html)). The downside is that have one have to realy on results in the litterature that might not be the easiest to prove if one wanted to make a self-contained proof...

Comment: @aes Thanks for your reply. It is odd to me because I think the limit of a pole is always $\infty$. I don't understand why we can use the limit as the value of $g(\frac \pi2)$. Or say why $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=\pi/2$. I drew the graph of $\sec(x)−\frac\pi 2\frac{\tan(x)}x$ and it seems to be continuous. Also from the graph, $\frac \pi 2$ and $-\frac \pi 2$ are not poles.

Comment: It's a different function than the original. It has no pole at $\pi/2$. Both $\mathrm{sec}(x)$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{tan}(x)/x$ have a pole there, but they both have simple poles and the same residue, and their difference is holomorphic near $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{E_n}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$$

[Using](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number#Euler_zigzag_numbers) $E_{n} \sim \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)/2} 4^{n+1}}{n+1}B_{n+1}$ [together with](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Asymptotic_approximation) $B_{2n} \sim (-1)^{n+1}4\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{\pi e}\right)^{2n}$ and [Stirlings approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{E_{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n-1} = \frac{4}{\pi}$$

so the terms in the series does not converge to $0$ and consequently the series does not converge.

Comment: Very nicely done!

Comment: It is $-\pi/2$ instead of $\pi/2$. It is true that the term does not converges to 0. But the odd terms are always negative but the even terms are always positive.

Comment: @Falang If a series is to converge then both odd and even terms have to converge to zero, i.e. we need $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$. The argument above shows that this is not the case here.

Comment: Hi, Winther. The power series is of course divergent, which is mentioned in the post. What I want to compute is the sum of the first $2n$ terms as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @Falang I see. I missed the $2k-1$ in the sum. For this case one can write the general term as $a_n = \left(\frac{E_{2n}}{(2n)!} - \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{E_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n}$. I will take a look at it when I get some time.

Comment: Right, exactly. Many thanks.